# Evaluate the integral $\int_{0}^{\pi}\!{{\rm e}^{x}}\sqrt {\sin \left( x \right) }\,{\rm d}x$.

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

Question inspired by [Does $\int _0^{\pi }e^x\sin ^n\left(x\right)\:\mathrm{d}x$ have a closed form?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3749152/442)

> Prove or disprove:
> $$
> \int_{0}^{\pi}\!{{\rm e}^{x}}\sqrt {\sin \left( x \right) }\,{\rm d}x=
> {\frac {{\pi}^{3/2}{{\rm e}^{\pi/2}}}{2^{3/2}\;\Gamma \left( 5/4+
> i/2 \right) \Gamma \left( 5/4-i/2 \right) }}
> $$

Comments:

(1) Maple says it is correct to 100 decimals.

(2) According to the cited problem,
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi}\!{{\rm e}^{x}} \left( \sin \left( x \right)  \right) ^{
n}\,{\rm d}x={\frac {\pi\,{{\rm e}^{\pi/2}}\Gamma \left( n+1 \right) 
}{{2}^{n}\Gamma \left( n/2+1+i/2 \right) \Gamma \left( n/2+1-i/2
 \right) }}
$$
holds for all nonnegative integers $n$.
May we conjecture that it holds for all
complex numbers $n$ except the negative integers?

Comment: Yes. Your integral equals $$2\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos(ix) \sqrt{\cos x} dx$$ there is a famous result for $$\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos(ax) \cos^b x dx$$ in terms of gamma function, it can be proved easily via contour integration: for example, see the middle of my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1414996.

Comment: So this will also be an answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3749152/442

Answer (score 3):

Here it is ...

*Gradshteyn, I. S.; Ryzhik, I. M.; Zwillinger, Daniel (ed.); Moll, Victor (ed.)*, [**Table of integrals, series, and products. Translated from the Russian. Translation edited and with a preface by Victor Moll and Daniel Zwillinger**](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/book/9780123849335), Amsterdam: Elsevier/Academic Press (ISBN 978-0-12-384933-5/hbk; 978-0-12-384934-2/ebook). xlv, 1133 p. (2015). [ZBL1300.65001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1300.65001).

**3.892.1**
$$
\int_0^\pi e^{i\beta x}\sin^{\nu-1} x\;dx =
\frac{\pi e^{i\,\beta\,\pi/2}}{2^{\nu-1}\,\nu\,\displaystyle
\operatorname{B}\left(\frac{\nu+\beta+1}{2},\frac{\nu-\beta+1}{2}\right)}
,\quad\operatorname{Re}\;\nu > -1
$$
Here $\operatorname{B}$ is the Beta function.